# Cómo pasar valores obtenidos de dos ciclos for a un objeto o array, siendo uno valor y otro clave para un update múltiple?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y me he topado con un problema, tengo una página en la muestro una tabla que con datos dinámicos, los cuales se pueden actualizar las zonas de dicho municipio una por una, el problema comienza al hacer que haga todas a la vez, tomando el id de municipio y el value del input que le corresponde a ese mismo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de obtener con una función los datos que requiero, el idmpio y los values de los input, pero no se como referenciar el value con el id que le corresponde a cada input y asi poder hacer el update en genral segun cada dato ingresado a su respectivo id de municipio.

Aqui envio los arreglos por AJAX, pero no me sirben así. Necesito uno asi {key:value}, donde key = valuesMpio y value = valuesZona.

```js
function updateAllZonas(){
    var class_mpioInput = document.getElementsByClassName("id_mpio");
    //console.log(class_mpioInput);
     var class_zonaInput = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
    //console.log(class_zonaInput);

    
        var valuesMpio = [];
        for(i=0;i<class_mpioInput.length;i++)
            if(class_mpioInput[i].value)
                valuesMpio.push(class_mpioInput[i].value);
        //console.log(valuesMpio);

        var valuesZona = [];
        for(i=0;i<class_zonaInput.length;i++)
            if(class_zonaInput[i])
                valuesZona.push(class_zonaInput[i].value);
        //console.log(valuesZona);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "db/updateAllZonas.php",
                data: {
                    valuesMpio: valuesMpio,
                    valuesZona: valuesZona
                },//capturo array     
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        /*var zonificacion=[valuesMpio,valuesZona]; //UNE LOD DOS ARREGLOS EN UNO SOLO
        console.log(zonificacion);*/
    
}
```

Aquí se forma la tabla dinamicamente con php desde una consulta, el formulario de los input lo utilizo para la actualización de datos uno por uno, eso ya funciona.
El botón actualizar es el que llama la función que me da los dos arreglos.

```html
<tr>
   <td class='td'>$munic->NOM_MPIO</td>
   <td class='td'>".number_format($munic->DO,1)."</td>
   <td class='td'></td>
   <td class='td'>
       <form action='db/updateZona.php' method='POST'>
           <input  class='id_mpio' name='id_mpio' value='$munic->ID_MPIO' style='display:none;'></input>
           <input  id='$munic->ID_MPIO' class='data' name='data' class='dataInput' required value='$munic->ZONA'></input>&nbsp;
           <button name='update'  title='Actualizar'><i class='fas fa-sync-alt' style='color:green;'></i></button>
       </form>
   </td>
</tr>
```

He intentado unir los arreglos obtenidos, pasarlo a un objeto pero no he logrado que quede así ejemplo, [key]=>value :

[valuesMpio]=>valuesZona

{
2001: 7,
2002: 5
}

Para después tratarlos con php en el update. Les comento, los datos los obtengo desde una consulta, espero entiendan mi idea, si tienen alguna otra solución mucho mejor, gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo envías los datos a PHP? De entrada, me parece que sería más fácil incluir in campo oculto con ID de municipio, cada índice va a estar asociado al input de zona.

Comment: Lo hago mediante Ajax, por método POST, envió al archivo updateAllZonas.php, donde pretendo hacer un implode para ejecutar el update multiple. El input donde se ingresa la zona tiene como "id" el valor de cada municipio y sobre ese mismo obtengo el value que se ingreso. como llevaría acabo tu idea?

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que armas el formulario y cómo lo envías por AJAX. Puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/513053/edit) las veces que sea necesario.

Comment: @Triby listo, no me agrega ya mas código, pero no es un formulario, es una tabla, los datos los envió mediante AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas crear solo un formulario, no uno para cada municipio. Cada fila con dos campos, uno oculto (`type="hidden"`) y el otro para teclear la zona. Ambos con el mismo nombre, pero con corchetes, para que sean tratados como arreglos:

```
<!-- Creas el formulario antes de la tabla, con ID -->
<form action='db/updateZona.php' method='POST' id='form-zona'>
<!-- Creas la tabla con sus respectivos encabezados -->

<!-- En el ciclo, llena la tabla -->
<tr>
   <td class='td'>$munic->NOM_MPIO</td>
   <td class='td'>".number_format($munic->DO,1)."</td>
   <td class='td'></td>
   <td class='td'>
       <input  type='hidden' name='id_mpio[]' value='$munic->ID_MPIO'>
       <input  type="number" name='data[]' class='dataInput' required value='$munic->ZONA'>
   </td>
</tr>

<-- Al salir del ciclo, cierras la tabla -->
<-- Tanto el botón como cierre de formulario van al final -->
<button name='update'  title='Actualizar'><i class='fas fa-sync-alt' style='color:green;'></i></button>
</form>
```

Con Javascript solo creas un objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) con el contenido del formulario, no necesitas recorrer los campos:

```
function updateAllZonas() {
    // Obtener formulario por ID
    let form = $('#form-zoza');
    // Creas el objeto, agregando [0] para usar el elemento HTMl del formulario
    let data = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "db/updateAllZonas.php",
        data: data ,//capturo array     
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Al procesar el formulario vas a recibir los dos campos como arreglos, uno para IDs y otro para zonas y solo debes usar el mismo índice para asociarlos:

```
<?php
// Obtener los dos arreglos
$ids = $_POST['id_mpio'];
$zonas = $_POST['data'];

// Recorrer, el índice de ID será el mismo que zonas
foreach($ids as $index => $id) {
    // Ya tienes la variable para ID, solo necesitas la de zona
    $zona = $zonas[$index];
    // Ahora ya puedes usar para actualizar, por ejemplo:
    $query = "UPDATE tabla SET zona = '$zona' WHERE id = $id";
}
```

**Importante:** Lo ideal es que uses consultas preparadas, la que puse es solo un ejemplo para ver cómo usar las variables.

**Nota:** La etiqueta `input` es de autocierre, por lo que no necesitas al final `</input>` y , aunque podría cerrarse con `/>`, no se recomienda en HTML5.

Comment: Lo intento y te comento que tal me fue, agradezco tu tiempo.

Comment: Amigo muchísimas gracias, me funciono a la perfección, la parte donde se procesan los arreglos para ejecutar el update múltiple, ya que los arreglos  los tenia, agradezco tu tiempo.